# Or of all pairs formed by taking xor of all the numbers in a list.

Tags: algorithm, xor, bit

Or of all pairs formed by taking xor of all the numbers in a list.

eg :   10,15,17

ans =  (10^15)|(15^17)|(10^17) = 31 . i have made an o(n*k) algo but need something better than that(n is number of entries and k is no. of bits in each number) .

Comment: "need something better than that" is pretty vague

Comment: (17^15) ? , (15^10) ? ...... are not included ?

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. Probably because it wouldn't change the calculation. `(A^B) == (B^A)`. So `(A^B) | (B^A)` will be the same as `(A^B)`.

Comment: What does `0 == a xor b` _mean_ for a single pair of bits; how about `1`?

Comment: @greybeard a xor b ==0 means a and b are equal .. didn't get your point .

Comment: Hardly needs telling. Now, what are the possible values for a and b for `a xor b` to be `false`, what if another variable enters the picture? _n_ other variables? Do bits of different position/value have any influence on each other with `xor` and `or`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be easiest to think in negatives here.

XOR is basically "not equal to"--i.e., it produces a result of 1 if and only if the two input bits are not equal to each other.

Since you're ORing all those results together, it means you get a 1 bit in the result anywhere there are at least two inputs that have different values at that bit position.

Inverting that, it means that we get a zero in the result *only* where every input has the same value at that bit position.

To compute that we can accumulate two intermediate values. For one, we AND together all the inputs. This will give us the positions at which every input had a one. For the other, we invert every input, and AND together all those results. This will tell us every position at which all the inputs had the value 0.

OR those together, and we have a value with a 1 where every input was equal, and a zero otherwise.

Invert that, and we get the desired result: 0 where all inputs were equal, and 1 where any was different.

This lets us compute the result with linear complexity (assuming each input value fits into a single word).